Cors config errors in Spring Boot deployment
I am having some trouble deploying my first Spring Application using Docker on my server. Currently I get CORS errors whenever I try anything using my React frontend. The cors works just fine on local host and if I use postman towards the server.
Out of many re-writes, this is currently where I am. Any ideas? Thank you so much!
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final static List<UserDetails> APPLICATION_USERS =

            Arrays.asList(
                    new User("admin", "admin", Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))),
                    new User("user", "user", Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")))
            );


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource(){
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("localhost:5173"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Content-Type"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}

Pretty much as many tutorials as I could find. All I got was some versions that threw a 403, like they didn't pass the authentication and others got a 401.

What does the Docker setup look like?  What URL is the React application trying to call?  If you can put both parts behind a reverse proxy, then the front end can make a path-only call to invoke the back end, which then won't be a cross-origin call; I have an example in this answer.

Please add the full CORS error message (as text, not as a picture) to your question. At least one issue with your configuration is that localhost:5173 is not a valid Web origin; you mean http://localhost:5173.
